# Why following GLES code generates DataAbort on Windows CE 6.0?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl-es, windows-ce

I'm developing Windows CE OpenGL application with Qt 4.8 and Open GL ES 1.0.
The problem is that following code causes unpredictable DataAbort Exception (unpredictable because it can occur in few seconds after start or in a few hours).
Can it be a driver issue or am I doing something wrong?
P.S. Tested this code without Qt - same behavior.

```
// GLWidget.hpp

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct drPoint {

    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;
    GLfloat R;
    GLfloat G;
    GLfloat B;
    GLfloat A;

};
#pragma pack(pop)

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget {

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GLWidget();


private:

    drPoint*    arr;
    unsigned int ui32Vbo;

    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int width, int height);

};

// GLWidget.cpp

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent) {}

void GLWidget::initializeGL() {

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glPointSize(1.0);

        arr = new drPoint[this->height()];

        for (int i = 0; i < this->height(); ++i) {

            arr[i].x    = 0;
            arr[i].y    = i;
            arr[i].R    = 1.0f;
            arr[i].G    = 0.0f;
            arr[i].B    = 0.0f;
            arr[i].A    = 1.0f;

        }

        glEnable(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnable(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        glGenBuffers(1, &ui32Vbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ui32Vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(drPoint) * this->height(), arr, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6, (void*)0);
        glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6, (void*)(sizeof(GLfloat) * 2));
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    }

void GLWidget::paintGL() {

    // Some buffer filling code

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ui32Vbo);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(drPoint) * this->height(), arr);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, this->height());

    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    float halfWidth  = width * 0.5f;
    float halfHeight = height * 0.5f;

    glOrthof(-halfWidth, halfWidth, -halfHeight, halfHeight, 0.0f, 10.0f);
    glTranslatef(-halfWidth, -halfHeight, 0.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

}

GLWidget::~GLWidget() {

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ui32Vbo);

    delete [] arr;

}
```

And exception looks like this:

```
13:08:40.534>  Exception 'Data Abort'(4) Thread-Id=04930016(pth=8674ec28) PC=81221700 BVA=b6200040, dwInfo = 00001008
13:08:40.534>  R0=00000049  R1=00000001  R2=82f994e8  R3=00000000
13:08:40.534>  R4=00000000  R5=00000001  R6=00000049  R7=82f99978
13:08:40.534>  R8=82f9ac38  R9=82f9df0c R10=82f9df0c R11=000007e0
13:08:40.534> R12=00000000  SP=d354f840  Lr=8121edf8 Psr=6000011f
13:08:40.574>  R7=81235608
13:08:40.574>  R8=00000001  R9=00000002 R10=82f9df0c R11=82f9df0c
13:08:40.574> R12=812360e0  SP=ffffc634  Lr=812360f8 Psr=60000193
13:08:40.574> Exception 'Data Abort' (4): Thread-Id=04930016(pth=8674ec28), Proc-Id=00400002(pprc=82fa1448) 'NK.EXE', VM-active=04920016(pprc=8674e9ac) 'opengl_hello.exe'
13:08:40.574> PC=8121a6d8(NK.EXE+0x0001a6d8) RA=812360f8(kernel.dll+0x0000e0f8) SP=ffffc634, BVA=00000000
13:08:40.534> 360f8(kernel.dll+0x0000e0f8) SP=ffffc634, BVA=00000000
13:08:40.534> e4) PC=8121a6d8 BVA=b6200040, dwInfo = 00001008
13:08:40.534>  R0=81235608  R1=60000113  R2=b6200000  R3=82f9ac38
13:08:40.659>  R4=82f9d424  R5=00000000  R6=82f9ecc0 Proc-Id=00400002(pprc=82fa1448) 'NK.EXE', VM-active=04920016(pprc=8674e9ac) 'opengl_hello.exe'
13:08:40.659> PC=c00bb9a4(k.coredll.dll+0x0001b9a4) RA=812354c4(kernel.dll+0x0000d4c4) SP=d354f558, BVA=ffffffff
```

Sorry for posting such type of question ("What's wrong with the code?!"), but I could not find any solution approximately for about a month.

P.S.
Used GLES 1.0 lib from official Texas Instruments sdk.
Hardware is DM3730 with PowerVR.
P.P.S.
Found out that such behavior occurs only in D1 power state (In D0 works OK, and in D2 drawing stops because of SystemIdle).

EDITED:
I changed code to following but still got same crash. For now it became more rare.

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct drPoint {

    GLfloat x;
    GLfloat y;

};
struct clrPoint {

    GLfloat R;
    GLfloat G;
    GLfloat B;
    GLfloat A;

};
#pragma pack(pop)

void GLWidget::initializeGL() {

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glPointSize(1.0);

        arr = new drPoint[this->height()];
        clr = new clrPoint[this->height()];

        for (int i = 0; i < this->height(); ++i) {

            arr[i].x    = 0;
            arr[i].y    = i;
            clr[i].R    = 1.0f;
            clr[i].G    = 0.0f;
            clr[i].B    = 0.0f;
            clr[i].A    = 1.0f;

        }

        glEnable(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnable(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    }

void GLWidget::paintGL() {

    // Some buffer filling code

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, arr);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, clr);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, this->height());

    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

}
```

And seems like without color everything works nice (or it just needs more time to crash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLES 1.0 doesn't support VBOs only "Vertex Arrays".

Your code is a mishmash between VBO and Vertex Array and you are not binding either one correctly.

Please consult [GLES](https://pandorawiki.org/GLES) for more information.

Comment: So you meant my code should looks something similar to this from your link:

`GLfloat vertices[] = {1,0,0, 0,1,0, -1,0,0};`
`glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);`
`glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);`
`glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);`
`glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);`

Comment: Sorry, I hurried a little bit. I stil got same exception with edited code posted in my question

Comment: Looks like it was a driver issue so we dropped WinCE support. Thanks